# Inno Setup TNewCheckListBox change a single check box properties

Tags: inno-setup

For a `TNewCheckListBox`, is it possible to change a single check box (added using the `AddCheckBox` function) properties? I have a number of check boxes in the `TNewCheckListBox` and I want to make some of the captions either, bold, or a different colour to indicate different states. I see there are properties for `Font` and `Color`, which apply to the whole `TNewCheckListBox`. What I think I am missing is a way of applying these to the individual check boxes. Is there some sort of CheckBox index value to which I can apply these? What I think I need is something like `CheckBoxCaption.Color[intIndex] := clGray;`, but this doesn't seem to exist. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The `TNewCheckListBox` is a wrapper around a Windows common control. IIRC, the ability to customize the appearance of individual items in the list wasn't available in that control until Windows 7, which means it probably isn't supported in the version of ComCtrls that is used by Inno Setup. I don't believe it's been updated to use that version of ComCtrls and add the necessary functionality to the control wrapper. Doing so, of course, would break installs on earlier OS versions than Win7. (I could be mistaken, which is why I'm posting this as a comment and not an answer.)

Comment: I agree, that it's not possible. All you can do is to replace the `TNewCheckListBox` with individual checkboxes and style each individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this is not possible.